# image came null from view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I need to get a photo from the view and in the controller, but always comes null

I need to get a photo from the view and in the controller, but it always comes null. I tried to download jpeg.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Avatar"></label><br />
        <input asp-for="Avatar" multiple>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = new User { Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, UserName = model.Email, Address = model.Address };

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await model.Avatar.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    user.Avatar = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
                var _result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (_result.Succeeded)
                {

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
                    //IdentityResult result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");

                    await _userRepository.SendConfirmEmailMessage(user.Email);


                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in _result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }

            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

RegisterViewModel

```
public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }
```

User

```
public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
```

Comment: use this `Register([FromBody]RegisterViewModel model)` instead of `Register(RegisterViewModel model)`

Comment: Try to use the browser's developer tools to check the passed data of the Request Header in Network . "**but it always comes null.**" Where is it null ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

RegisterViewModel

```
[FromForm]
public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }
```

And remove `ApiController` attribute

Comment: I put `[FromForm]`, did not help, what did you mean about `ApiController?`